# python manipulate parent class attribute when instance is deleted

Tags: python, class

I am trying to make self contained data persistent class that will save the instance into a pickle or json file, i have analagize my code,

```py
class Base:
    stack = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        cls.stack.append(self)
        return self

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(A, self).__init__(name)

    def __del__(self):
        Base.stack.remove(self)

class B(Base):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(B, self).__init__(name)


print(Base.stack)
a = A('test 1')
b = B('test 2')
print(Base.stack)
a = None # Have also tried del a, so that __del__ is invoked.
print(Base.stack)
```

here i'll persist the stack list in some way which i havent implemented in the psuedo code, but i had it under main code,

when the subclass instance is created it should be added in the base class attribute which is right now a list
and when the subclass instance is deleted it should be deleted from there.
i had changed the **del** method, but it seems not to work.

why the results is this:

```
[]

[<__main__.A object at 0x000001D549A59910>, <__main__.B object at 0x000001D549A5AC10>]

[<__main__.A object at 0x000001D549A59910>, <__main__.B object at 0x000001D549A5AC10>]
```

and not this:

```
[]

[<__main__.A object at 0x000001D549A59910>, <__main__.B object at 0x000001D549A5AC10>]

[<__main__.B object at 0x000001D549A5AC10>]
```

i know **del** is the finalizer which will be invoked by garbage collector when reference to that isntance is zero, and thats what i did.

Comment: Its because after `a = None`, there is still a reference to `a` in `Base.stack` so it can't be deleted as it can still be accessed through `Base.stack`. Perhaps you could make `Base.stack` a list of weak reference using the [`weakref`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) module

Comment: is there a way to self remove an instance, coz i  am thinking of making a function that when called will remove it self from the stack list and delete it self

Comment: i searched there is no way to delete it self, can only delete reference

Comment: You can remove `a` from `Base.stack` by doing `Base.stack.remove(a)`.